# Find the page size in a PDF file using LaTeX

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, page

I sometimes use `LaTeX` in conjunction with `pdfpages` package to manipulate the pages of a PDF file (not necessarily created by `LaTeX`), operations like combining several pages into one, or changing the order of pages.

The question I have is how to find the size of each page in an external PDF file? I want to use `pdfpages` to reorder the pages by height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably much easier ways to do this, but you could use `\settoheight` to measure the height of a page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\imageheight}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{printlen} % only for demonstration

\begin{document}

\settoheight{\imageheight}{\includegraphics[page=1]{example-image-a4}}


\uselengthunit{cm}\printlength{\imageheight} % only for demonstration
\end{document}
```